# How do I establish a MySQL connection?

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting a weird exception when I run the code.

```
public MySQL()
    {

        Connection conn = null;
        String userName = "admin";
        String password = "admin";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testbase",userName,password);
            System.out.println("CONNECTED");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Can't connect to database!");
        }
    }
```

All I am getting is this exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
Can't connect to database!  at com.baze.gimnazija.MySQL.<init>(MySQL.java:15)
    at com.baze.gimnazija.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I have the library connected.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

That's not the name of the class. Java is **case sensitive**, so you must respect the capital letters.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

If you use Mysql 8, then the driver class has changed:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Note: if you're using Java 7 or superior, you can omit that line of code.

Comment: I am getting the same error again.

Comment: Answer updated, in case you use MySQL 8.